# How to run lwjgl with jnlp on webstart?

Tags: java, applet, lwjgl, java-web-start, jnlp

I've been searching for a proper way to run an **lwjgl** applet for a while now.
I tried the old school method using the appletloader, but this didn't work out for me.
So the alternative would be webstart/jnlp.

Could someone explain to me what I need for this .jnlp/.html , because I can't find a relative example that extensively explain everything.

I guess what I am asking for is a tutorial (;.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle tutorials for JNLP deployment are fairly complete and easy.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html

Setting up a JNLP is similar to a manifest in jar, you have to specify the main class, class path, set permissions, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I was already using this as example but I get a strange error that I cant seem to find anywhere -.-

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to load lwjgl from my jnlp. Note especially the nativelibs at the end that are in addition to the main lwjgl and lwjgl-util jars. LWJGL distribute these as plain native library files. You will need to package them in jar files - see further down.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BitMinter Client JNLP file -->
<jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="https://bitminter.com/client/"
      href="bitminter.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>BitMinter Client</title>
    <vendor>BitMinter.com</vendor>
    <homepage href="https://bitminter.com/"/>
    <description>BitMinter</description>
    <description kind="short">Mining for the digital mint</description>
    <icon href="bitminter256x256.png" width="256" height="256"/>
    <icon href="bitminter64x64.png"   width="64"  height="64"/>
    <icon href="bitminter48x48.png"   width="48"  height="48"/>
    <icon href="bitminter32x32.png"   width="32"  height="32"/>
    <icon href="bitminter16x16.png"   width="16"  height="16"/>
    <icon kind="splash" href="bitmintersplash.png"/>
    <shortcut online="true">
      <desktop/>
      <menu submenu="BitMinter"/>
    </shortcut>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <update check="always" policy="always"/>
  <application-desc main-class="com.bitminter.client.Main"/>
  <resources>
    <java version="1.6+" initial-heap-size="40m" max-heap-size="800m"
          java-vm-args=""/>
    <jar href="bitminter.jar"/>
    <!-- long list of regular jars left out -->
    <jar href="lwjgl-2.8.4.jar"/>
    <jar href="lwjgl_util-2.8.4.jar"/>
  </resources>

  <!-- LWJGL Linux 64-bit native libraries -->
  <resources os="Linux" arch="amd64">
    <nativelib href="lwjgl-amd64-linux.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Linux" arch="x86_64">
    <nativelib href="lwjgl-amd64-linux.jar"/>
  </resources>

  <!-- LWJGL Linux 32-bit native libraries -->
  <resources os="Linux" arch="x86">
    <nativelib href="lwjgl-x86-linux.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Linux" arch="i386">
    <nativelib href="lwjgl-x86-linux.jar"/>
  </resources>

  <!-- LWJGL Windows 64-bit native libraries -->
  <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
    <nativelib href="lwjgl-amd64-win.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
    <nativelib href="lwjgl-amd64-win.jar"/>
  </resources>

  <!-- LWJGL Windows 32-bit native libraries -->
  <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
    <nativelib href="lwjgl-x86-win.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows" arch="i386">
    <nativelib href="lwjgl-x86-win.jar"/>
  </resources>

  <!-- LWJGL MAC OS/X native libraries -->
  <resources os="Mac">
    <nativelib href="lwjgl-macosx.jar"/>
  </resources>
</jnlp>
```

LWJGL native libraries are distributed in folders for each operating system with 32 and 64 bit libs lumped together. We'll need to make 64 and 32 bit jar files for each operating system we wish to support, except for Mac OS X which has 32 and 64 bit in the same files. If you don't need all the native libs, then you need only include the ones you do need. Here's an example using ant to create the jars with only the main lwjgl native libs, leaving out the input and openal parts.

```
<!-- LWJGL -->
<jar jarfile="${build.unsigned}/lwjgl-amd64-linux.jar">
  <fileset file="${lib}/native/lwjgl/linux/liblwjgl64.so"/>
</jar>
<jar jarfile="${build.unsigned}/lwjgl-x86-linux.jar">
  <fileset file="${lib}/native/lwjgl/linux/liblwjgl.so"/>
</jar>
<jar jarfile="${build.unsigned}/lwjgl-amd64-win.jar">
  <fileset file="${lib}/native/lwjgl/windows/lwjgl64.dll"/>
</jar>
<jar jarfile="${build.unsigned}/lwjgl-x86-win.jar">
  <fileset file="${lib}/native/lwjgl/windows/lwjgl.dll"/>
</jar>
<jar jarfile="${build.unsigned}/lwjgl-macosx.jar">
  <fileset file="${lib}/native/lwjgl/macosx/liblwjgl.jnilib"/>
</jar>
```

The jar files we create here are the ones loaded by the jnlp above.

You could also create the jar files from the command line, using the jar utility:

```
jar cf lwjgl-amd64-linux.jar linux/liblwjgl64.so
jar cf lwjgl-x86-linux.jar linux/liblwjgl.so
jar cf lwjgl-amd64-win.jar windows/lwjgl64.dll
jar cf lwjgl-x86-win.jar windows/lwjgl.dll
jar cf lwjgl-macosx.jar macosx/liblwjgl.jnilib
```

Comment: Sure. I put in the complete jnlp file except I removed some regular jars from the list to reduce the size a bit.

Comment: I also added instructions for how to create the nativelib jars. It's been so long since I set this up, I had forgotten the native libs are not distributed as jars from the LWJGL site.

Comment: I added a command line alternative to the ant tasks. If you need to include more libs (libopenal64.so etc) in each jar just add their filenames at the end of each command.

Comment: I gave up, I can't get it to work. No one can tell me why.
Thanks for trying to help though